Getting 403 forbidden error when useWatchContractEvent hook is used in next, wagmi, react
I am getting 403 forbidden on every interval multiple times. I used the useWatchContractEvent() hook from wagmi in my next js app.
Getting same  error multiple times in intervals:
POST https://sepolia.optimism.io/ 403 (Forbidden)
This is the code:
useWatchContractEvent({
    address: FactoryContract,
    abi: FactoryContractABI,
    eventName: "RaffleCreated",
    pollingInterval: 100_000,
    chainId: optimismSepolia.id,
    syncConnectedChain: true,
    onLogs(logs) {
        console.log("New logs!", logs);
    },
    onError(error) {
        console.log("Error", error);
    },
});


You need to use some third-party RPC provider (like Alchemy or Infura) url in the transports object of your wagmi.ts file:
Using Alchemy RPC Provider URL
transports: {
  [optimismSepolia.id]: http(`https://opt-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_API_KEY}`),
},

Using Infura RPC Provider URL
transports: {
  [optimismSepolia.id]: http(`https://optimism-sepolia.infura.io/v3/${process.env.INFURA_API_KEY}`),
},

